# remove quotes from fields while loading data into hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I want to load a table with input data into hive. I have data in the following format.

```
100510;LOCAL CARD;;;;UNITED KINGDOM;GB;GBR;826
100515;LOCAL CARD;;;;NORWAY;NO;NOR;578
103753;LOCAL CARD;I&M BANK;DEBIT;PREPAID;KENYA;KE;KEN;404
104001;LOCAL CARD;LUXURY JEWELLERY CLASS (LJC) - TDFS;;;CANADA;CA;CAN;124
```

I want to load this table in hive from hdfs but because some columns do not contains data its giving me double quotes in results.
I want to ignore them.

Comment: In place of empty double quotes(""), what do you want to display??

Comment: I want it to be vacant. no value i.e blank space

Comment: What format is your table stored in?

Comment: The format of my table is CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control how Hive handles nulls using `serialization.null.format`.
To create a table:

```
create table <your table>
<column list>
rowformat delimited fields terminated by <your delimiter>
TBLPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = '');
```

To change an existing table

```
alter table <your table>  set TBLPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = '');
```

Comment: After running the above query I am getting null values, But how could I replace these null values with blank space.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  What do you want for nulls, an empty string, or something else?

Comment: yeah I want empty string instead of null.

Comment: I don't think you can set it to an empty string.  You can set it to be null, or any character you want, but not an empty string.